# Update Cursor Function in Arc Pro doesn't show errors, but will not Execute

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I wrote this to run in ArcGIS Pro to populate some cells in an attribute table if one of the other cells is true.  When I run the script, nothing happens in the table and I do not get an error message.  Am I forgetting some portion of the code that will execute it? Thanks!

```
import arcpy
fc = 'C://file//path//folder.gdb//featureclass'

fields = ['OBJECT', 'PROJECT', 'LENGTH', 'ID', 'etc.', 'FIELD', 'FIELD2', 
'FIELD3', 'FIELD4', 'DV......']


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if(row[10] == "AERIAL"):
            row[15] == "N" and row[18] == "AER::"
            rows.updateRow(row)
        else:
            if(row[10] == "BURIED"):
                row[15] == "Y" and row[18] == "BUR::"
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I think ArcPy questions are more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning new values to the rows before trying to update it.

I think it's a syntax problem.

Those two lines:

```
row[15] == "N" and row[18] == "AER::"
row[15] == "Y" and row[18] == "BUR::"
```

Are just testing if `row[15]` value is equal to `"N"` or `"Y"` and `row[18]` value is equal to `"AER::"` or `"BUR::"`. Those line just return `True` or `False`, the row values are not modified.

If what you want to do is to assign new values to `row[15]` and `row[18]`, you have to do as the code below:

```
import arcpy
fc = 'C://file//path//folder.gdb//featureclass'

fields = ['OBJECT', 'PROJECT', 'LENGTH', 'ID', 'etc.', 'FIELD', 'FIELD2', 
'FIELD3', 'FIELD4', 'DV......']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in rows:
        if row[10] == "AERIAL":
            row[15] = "N" #assign value "N" to row[15]
            row[18] = "AER::" #assign value "AER::" to row[18]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        elif row[10] == "BURIED":
            row[15] = "Y" #assign value "Y" to row[15]
            row[18] = "BUR::" #assign value "BUR::" to row[18]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: That did not work.  It recognizes the correct table because it can print the values, it just will not input new values.

Comment: Ok see my edited answer. if it still not works, verify that `row[10]` are populated with `"AERIAL"` or `"BURIED"` values only. The problem is probably that the conditions are never met.

Comment: in your answer there is an eror: 
`cursor.updateRow(row) `
should be replaced by :
`rows.updateRow(row)`

Comment: @XtianGIS thank you for noticing that error. It is repaired now